# Passing the content of a manual created JSONObject to Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

if I want to get my databaseentry of a Entity I get the right result, but this result has linebreaks, which I dont wanna have. What I want is this ( a jsonfile ):

```
    {
  "id" : 20706,
  "name" : "Ecole des Ponts ParisTech",
  "institution_type" : {
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "Research facility"
  },
```

But what I get is that:

```
{"institution":["{\r\n  \"id\" : 20706,\r\n  \"name\" : \"Ecole des Ponts ParisTech\",\r\n  \"institution_type\" : {\r\n    \"id\" : 2,\r\n    \"name\" : \"Research facility\"\r\n  },
```

My code to get this is:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = ObjectMapperFactory.getObjectMapper();
EditorialDAO dao = EditorialManager.dao();
    String valueValue = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(dao.get(Institution.class,20706));
```

Yeah I want a String, but not with linebreaks and \ for my " .

My ObjectMapper is declared as followed:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
    objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_KEYS_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.EAGER_SERIALIZER_FETCH, true);
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
```

EDIT: 
Next code after getting valueValue:

```
String response = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dao.get(Basic.class, 323));
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);       
                jsonObject.put(institution, valueValue);
                response = jsonObject.toString();
                dao.merge(objectMapper.readValue(response, Basic.class));
```

If I try to merge i get this error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of Institution: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value();
```

What I dont get: I just put that inpout from database exactly into my JSON and my Basic.class Entity has the Type Institution.

```
@Entity
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Basis implements{

    @Id
    @SortableField
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "basis_generator", sequenceName = "basis_id_basis_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "basis_generator")
    @Column(name="id_basis")
    @JsonView(View.Minimal.class)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JsonView(View.Minimal.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_institution")
    private Institution institution;
```

Comment: @second Not accurate. Whitespace between values is meaningless.

Comment: OP, it looks like you're running your string through the mapper _twice_.

Comment: Edit with some more infos.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Yes, you are right. The standard describes them as insignificant. However if the OP uses pretty print (and/or `INDENT_OUTPUT`) linefeeds and indentation will be added.

Comment: I set the INDENT_OUTPUT to false and delete the prettyprinter now. It works after getting this from dao. But if I add this to my jsonobject, the linebreaks are still available again :/

Comment: No the problem are this \" things. After put my valuevalue into my jsonobject, the new valuevalue has the linebrackets and before every " is a \, also before my { . This is not json valid ! cause of this I can merge my entity. I can work with patterns to replace them, but its a dirty solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210657/discussion-between-second-and-dennis).

Comment: @Dennis: I reworded the question-title and updated the tags to put the focous on the actual problem. Feel free to reword the question so that the problem description becomes more transparent in case other users face the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to not pass the `valueValue` directly into you `jsonObject`. Instead it needs to be a `JsonObject` of its own.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);       
jsonObject.put(institution, new JSONObject(valueValue));
```

---

Directly passing the json value leads to the following output, where the quotes are escaped and additional quotes have been added around the value.
This way should only be used for **primitive** types.

```
{"institution":"{\"id\":20706,\"name\":\"Ecole des Ponts ParisTech\",\"institutionType\":{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Research facility\"}}","id":1}
```

---

If wrapped into a new `JsonObject`, the result is a a correct representation, which `jackson` can handle.

```
{"institution":{"name":"Ecole des Ponts ParisTech","institutionType":{"name":"Research facility","id":2},"id":20706},"id":1}
```

---

Ps.:
Whether the original string was in the pretty print format or not does not matter.